# Problems with installing Flutter seemingly caused by android studio

Tags: android, windows, flutter, android-studio

So I want to install flutter.
Doing this, I am following the flutter installation guide :
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows

When running flutter doctor in the flutter_console.bat it finds two issues

1. [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
   X Android license status unknown.
   Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
2. [!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
   X Unable to find bundled Java version.

I do have Android studio installed from the following website:
https://developer.android.com/studio
for Windows 64x
When following the setup guides like here :
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup

It seems like there should be an environmental variable named Android_Home.
I do not have that.

Through android studio I have installed the last three android SDK this should not be a problem.

I also have the latest java version installed and can program in java using VS Code, so I don't understand issue number 2.

Answer (score 0):

For first problem run below command in your terminal and please type y for accept the licences...

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Comment: It returns the following error :
Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to
resolve this.

Which I don't fully understand, I should have all tools provided by the newest android studio setup wizard.

Comment: 1.Open Android Studio
2.Tools Menu, SDK Manager
3.In the window that comes up there are inner panels, choose SDK Tools panel
4.Tick Android SDK Command-line Tools
5.Choose Apply button near the bottom of the window
At that point, you will be prompted to accept the SDK license and the command line tools will be installed. Your license issue should now be resolved.

FYI, the command line tools will add a new folder cmdline-tools inside your SDK Folder. If you look in there cmdline-tools/latest/bin you will see sdkmanager - but your license issue should already be resolved.

Comment: Thank you, this resolved the first problem :)